# Matplotlib 1.4.0 installation gets stuck

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, virtualenv, python-3.2

I'm trying to install matplotlib in a virtualenv with Python 3.2.3. I've tried installing it both from the downloadable archive and with pip. In both cases the installation process gets stuck until I interrupt it with ^C. Why does this happen?

Here is the output of the installation process:

```
(virtenv)scintillo@lakka:~/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0$ python setup.py build
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.0]
                python: yes [3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 14:44:27)  [GCC
                        4.7.2]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.9.0]
                   six: yes [six was not found.]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                        with Python 3.x.  Using local copy]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.4.9]
                   png: yes [version 1.2.49]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                        to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                        to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                        may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                        to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                        to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                        may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
^CException KeyboardInterrupt in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/scintillo/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0/setupext.py", line 1949, in check_requirements
    msg = p.map(self.callback, [self])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 559, in get
    raise self._value
setupext.CheckFailed: PySide not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 154, in <module>
    result = package.check()
  File "/home/users/scintillo/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0/setupext.py", line 491, in check
    additional_info = self.check_requirements()
  File "/home/users/scintillo/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0/setupext.py", line 1956, in check_requirements
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 465, in join
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/process.py", line 147, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 147, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 132, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: `setupext.CheckFailed: PySide not found`? Maybe you should install it. I don't know if that's actually the problem, but there's no harm trying.

Comment: @Veedrac Doesn't quite explain the freezing but I'll try.

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3444 The problem is with python 3.2 which mpl no longer officially supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib 1.4.0 doesn't support Python 3.2. You have to install matplotlib 1.3.1. This can be done with pip using command `pip install matplotlib==1.3.1`.

See this issue for additional details: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3444